# eplain packages with plain tex no longer have all needed definitions

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, texlive-2019, protected-macro, eplain

If one uses tex rather than pdftex, one gets errors when inputting certain packages with eplain. For example, let test.tex be this file:

```
\input /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/eplain/eplain
\beginpackages
   \usepackage{graphicx}  
\endpackages

\bye
```

Running `tex test.tex` gives

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(./test.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/eplain/eplain.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.118 \protected
                \def\includegraphics{%
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 \edef\Gin@gzext{\detokenize
                                 {gz}}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.413 \protected
                \long\def\rotatebox#1#2{%
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.482 \protected
                \def\scalebox#1{%
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.501 \protected
                \def\reflectbox{\Gscale@box-1[1]}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.502 \protected
                \def\resizebox{%
? 
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.239 \protected
                \def\rotatebox{%
? 
) [1] )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 236 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

whereas running `pdftex test.tex` gives no errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/eplain/eplain.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

There were no problems with TeX Live 2015/Debian:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(./test.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/eplain/eplain.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

What is the proper fix for this?

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX packages assume the presence of etex extensions such as `\protected` sometimes you get lucky and none are actually used but graphics (now) uses `\protected`.

The etex extensions are available in all engines (pdftex, luatex, xetex, etex) but the `tex` format uses the classical tex unextended format as required to use the `tex` name.

So you can simply use etex (or equivalently pdftex with `\pdfoutput=0`) to use plain tex with dvi output.